# Populate a checkbox list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Given an array that contains a list of strings (obtained using an api call), I want to populate a checkbox list with that array. I'm trying the following:

HTML code:

```
....
<div class="form-group">
    <label><lang code="Categories"></lang></label>
    <div class="checkbox" id="category-checkbox">
    </div>
    <p class="help-block"><lang code="Categories (3 max)"></lang></p>
</div>
....
```

javascript code:

```
    ....
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            $('#category-checkbox').append("<label><input type=\"checkbox\"><lang code="+data[i].title+"></lang></label>");
        }
    ....
```

Where data is the array of strings.

My question is why is this not working.

Comment: Try console.log the data and show it if you would not mind please. My guess from this is the data is coming back slightly different but it's hard to tell without seeing it

Comment: What if you try to add quotes before and after `data[i].title`? Something like: `<lang code=\""+data[i].title+"\"></lang>` so that your title is stored within quotes?

Comment: is `lang` a valid html tag?

Comment: I've tried adding quotes and still doesn't populate the list. Here's the output of console.log(data), both the object and each element in the object:

Comment: [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]0: Objecttitle: "Restaurantes y Gourmet"__proto__: Object1: Objecttitle: "Hombre"__proto__: Object2: Objecttitle: "Mujer"__proto__: Object3: Objecttitle: "Eventos"__proto__: Object4: Objecttitle: "Gastronomía"__proto__: Object5: Objecttitle: "Niños"__proto__: Object6: Objecttitle: "Tecnología"__proto__: Object7: Objecttitle: "Viajes y Turismo"__proto__: Object8: Objecttitle: "Hogar y Decoración"__proto__: Object9: Objecttitle: "Ocio y Entretenimiento"__proto__: Object10: Objecttitle: "Salud y Belleza"__...

Comment: lang is a custom tag

Comment: So if you try: `console.log(data[0].title)` you get **Restaurantes y Gourmet**?

Comment: "Restaurantes y Gourmet", yes (with the double quotes)

Comment: Do you have your code inside a `document.ready` function?  It works fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/sh04gdbe/

Answer (score 0):

If the title has any spaces, etc. you'll want it escaped. Safer to let jQuery handle that for you:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var lang = $('<lang>').
    attr('code', data[i].title);

  $('<label>').
    append('<input type="checkbox">').
    append(lang).
    appendTo('#category-checkbox');
}
```

```js
var data = [
  { title: 'one' },
  { title: 'one two three' },
  { title: 'embedded "quotes" and <' }
];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var lang = $('<lang>').
    attr('code', data[i].title);

  $('<label>').
    append('<input type="checkbox">').
    append(lang).
    appendTo('#category-checkbox');
}
```

```css
lang:after {
   content: attr(code);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='category-checkbox'></div>
```

Comment: Trying that works if I put it hard-coded in the javascript console of Chrome, but not when the page loads ):

Comment: Where are you loading it? If it's in the head, or early in the body, and `#category-checkbox` doesn't exist yet, nothing will happen. Or, of course, if jQuery isn't yet loaded. Put it inside `$(document).ready( ... ) `.

Comment: After loading the html

Comment: Finally I've fixed it, you were